# What is the intersection of $SL(3,\mathbb{R})$ and $SU(2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-groups

I want to know what the following Lie group is,
$$\text{SL}(3,\mathbb{R})\cap \text{SU}(2)$$.

My strategy is as follows: a matrix in $\text{SL}(3,\mathbb{R})$ is,
$$M_{1}\in \text{GL}(3,\mathbb{R}),\quad \text{det}(M_{1})=1$$
and a matrix in $SU(2)$ is,
$$M_{2}\in \text{GL}(2,\mathbb{C}),\quad M_{2}\cdot M_{2}^{\dagger}=\mathbb{1},\quad \text{det}(M_{2})=1$$
Then a matrix in the intersection should satisfy the union of all the above conditions. Then I don't know where to go.

One thing I was thinking is that $\text{SU}(2)\subset \text{SU}(3)$ and so $\text{SL}(3,\mathbb{R})\cap \text{SU}(2)\subset \text{SL}(3,\mathbb{R})\cap \text{SU}(3)$, but $\text{SL}(3,\mathbb{R})\cap \text{SU}(3)=\text{SO}(3)$ (as this is just the real $\text{SU}(3)$ matrices). So the answer should be a subset of $\text{SO}(3)$ I think.

Can someone help or give some hints? I get the feeling I'm missing a simple method.

Comment: I don't see why the answer should not depend on how you embed $SL(3,\Bbb R)$ and $SU(2,\Bbb C)$ in some $GL(n,\Bbb C)$.

Comment: ok thanks. In that case, is it possible to embed $SU(2)$ in $GL(3,\mathbb{R})$ and take the intersection there?

Comment: Why should we believe the question even makes sense? Where did you get this?

Comment: @HairlessVictory Even if it were possible, and I don't know if it is, the intersection could still depend on the specific embedding.

Comment: Now that you have made me think about it some more, I realise that my motivation was flawed and this intersection is actually not of interest to me. So I have no good reason to expect the question to make sense. Thank you for the comments :) Perhaps this question can be removed now.